# HERE API autosuggest not returning any data for query 3 chars long

Tags: here-api

I have a problem with autosuggest feature in HERE API not returning any results for query containing 3 characters, but returning proper result for query with 4 characters, for example:

[https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=52.2330653,20.921114,11&in=countryCode:DEU,NLD,BEL&resultTypes=locality&apiKey=[API_KEY]&q=ber](https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=52.2330653,20.921114,11&in=countryCode:DEU,NLD,BEL&resultTypes=locality&apiKey=%5BAPI_KEY%5D&q=ber)

returns empty result, but:

[https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=52.2330653,20.921114,11&in=countryCode:DEU,NLD,BEL&resultTypes=locality&apiKey=[API_KEY]&q=berl](https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=52.2330653,20.921114,11&in=countryCode:DEU,NLD,BEL&resultTypes=locality&apiKey=%5BAPI_KEY%5D&q=berl)

suggests Berlin as expected.

Why first query is not returning any data?

Comment: My first guess is that the API needs a minimum of 4 characters for the `q` parameter. Do the API docs specify that in any way?

Comment: I don't see any parameter in docs for that https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html

Comment: One more thing, for other queries 3-chars long it works as expected.

Comment: This doesn't affect the results, but please note that there's an extraneous comma in the geocoordinate provided in the requests.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be a bug. I have checked and the various query lengths all work fine, *except* when the `in=countryCode` parameter is used. I've filed a ticket with the relevant team and will have this looked at.